# 11:5 error 'router' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am trying to make an object from ROUTER class in JAVASCRIPT file and this error happens

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

import Router from 'vue-router'


Vue.use(Router);
var router = new Router();
new Vue({
    render: h => h(App),

}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: You are not using router variable so you can remove it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a `router` instance but never used it with `Vue`.
You must link both together by doing:

```
var router = new Router();
new Vue({
    router, // here we link the router instance to the Vue instance
    render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

As said here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript

There error you see is because you created/declared a variable but never used it.